# How to get JSON into my app after I locate it in Chrome's Developer tools?

Tags: javascript, ios, json, google-chrome

So I work frequently with a company and they outsource their website to another company to manage. I'm trying to pull the website's data into my app to populate a UITableViewController but I couldn't find the source page for the html page the site presented (http://www.pointstreak.com/prostats/scoringleaders.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=12983). I used Chrome's Developer Tools and found the site's table data in JSON (I think, I'm not sure). It begins like this:

```
<table width="98%" class="tablelines" cellpadding="2" border="0" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="17" class="maincolor">
            <a href="scoringleaders.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=12983&position=D">View Defense</a> | <a href="scoringleaders.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=12983&position=F">View Forwards</a> | <a href="scoringleaders.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=12983">All Positions</a>             </td>  
          </tr>
          <tr align="center" class="tableheader"> 
            <td width="2%">RK</td>
            <td align="left" width="20%"><a class="sort" href="scoringleaders.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=12983&sortby=name">PLAYER</a></td>
            <td width="6%">TEAM</td>
            <td width="6%"><a class="sort" href="scoringleaders.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=12983&sortby=pos">Pos.</a></td>
            <td width="6%"><a class="sort" href="scoringleaders.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=12983&sortby=gp">GP</a></td>
            <td width="6%"><a class="sort" href="scoringleaders.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=12983&sortby=g">G</a></td>
            <td width="6%"><a class="sort" href="scoringleaders.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=12983&sortby=a">A</a></td>
            <td width="6%"><a class="sort" href="scoringleaders.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=12983">PTS</a></td>
            <td width="6%"><a class="sort" href="scoringleaders.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=12983&sortby=plusminus"> +/-</a></td><td width="6%"><a class="sort" href="scoringleaders.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=12983&sortby=pim">PIM</a></td>
            <td width="6%"><a class="sort" href="scoringleaders.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=12983&sortby=ppg">PP</a></td>
            <td width="6%"><a class="sort" href="scoringleaders.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=12983&sortby=ppa">PPA</a></td>
            <td width="6%"><a class="sort" href="scoringleaders.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=12983&sortby=shg">SH</a></td>
            <td width="6%"><a class="sort" href="scoringleaders.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=12983&sortby=sha">SHA</a></td>
            <td width="6%"><a class="sort" href="scoringleaders.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=12983&sortby=gwg">GWG</a></td>
            <td width="6%"><a class="sort" href="scoringleaders.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=12983&sortby=shots">SHOTS</a></td>
            <td width="6%"><a class="sort" href="scoringleaders.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=12983&sortby=spct">S%</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr align="center" class="maincolor"> 
            <td class="light">
            1               </td> 
            <td  class="light"align="left"><a href="playerpage.html?playerid=7208177&seasonid=12983">Johnson, Adam</a></td>
            <td><a href="teamplayerstats.html?teamid=3138&seasonid=12983">SC</a></td>
```

And I think it's JSON. Now since this is just in Chrome's Developer Tools and not what comes up on the page when I type in a certain URL, is there any way to load this data into my tableView?

Moreover, is there anyway to keep a live version of this that feeds my app, as a simple copy and paste will keep it static? Thanks.

Comment: If I've understood it correctly, you'd like to get the ajax url that created this html. In the developer console in network tab you can filter for xhr requests, then you'll see the ajax call to the followin url: [http://www.pointstreak.com/ajax/trending_ajax.html?action=leaguescoreboard&leagueid=49](http://www.pointstreak.com/ajax/trending_ajax.html?action=leaguescoreboard&leagueid=49).

Comment: Would there be another page like that but which contains the info that populates the "Scoring Leaders" table?

Comment: I think the rest of the page is done with severside scripting. It seems like the scoring leaders table is inserted into a script tag with php. See source line 318 of scoringleaders.html. The line starts with `var team_source = [ { label: "Bloomington (USHL 2014/2015)", ...`

Comment: So do you think there is no way to get it for me without working with the site directly?

Comment: That is absolutely not [JSON](http://json.org/).

Comment: The html table is created with a js object so they can apply filters to it and it is possible to get that object from the page. I'll post the script later when I'm at my notebook. The script uses an ajax request over a http proxy because of CORS and then it uses a regular expr. to get the object as a string from the html script tag. To create the object it uses eval. It works but it's a bit tricky.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use my code below only for development and if you're working with the site creator. It looks to my a bit like stealing the data from their page.

It would be better if they could implement a request for JSON or JSONP into their backend so you could add a url parameter like `&format=jsonp`.

Any way, below is the script to get the data from the page. Details to the script see my comment above. You can also find it at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/fbk7eme5/).

You could probably also parse the data from HTML tags if there wouldn't be the JS object but that's a bit more complicated but also possible.

(If you're at the same origin you don't need the http proxy.)

It's not the score table but the info to the teams (name + url to the team info page).
The score table is created with PHP. You can see this because if you're using a filter at the table it creates a new request to the backend.

I think the best would be to talk with the site creator and check if they could implement the API for JSON(P) requests for you. 
So you can create a frontend app easily with-out fiddling the data from there.

---

**Update 6th April 2015 (12:12 UTC)**

The extracting of HTML tags is possible - see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/Lh7ph6pd/). As mentioned before, it's more complicated.

But I think the best is to use the generated JSON and use a mocking service like [mocky.io](http://www.mocky.io) because it's faster and OK if you just need it for testing your app.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.pointstreak.com/prostats/scoringleaders.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=12983',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        //console.log(data);
        regEx = /var team_source\s*=\s*\[([^\]]+)]/; // regex to filter the team_source variable
      
        // now find the js object with the braces [ ]
        console.log(regEx.exec(data));
        eval(regEx.exec(data)[0]);
        //var team = new Object(team_source);
        console.log(team_source[0].label); // now you can work with the js object
        $('#output').html(JSON.stringify(team_source, null, 2));
        
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: I plan to talk with the site creators, but don't know exactly what I'll ask them to do. If I ask them to "implement a request for JSON or JSONP into their backend so [I] could add a url parameter like &format=jsonp" would I just need to add that to the url and then I'd have the JSON data, and then could turn that into an NSArray/Dictionary via Xcode? Thank you very much, by the way.

Comment: Yes, that should work, but I don't know Xcode. You could have a look at other APIs that are available to get an idead of what you need. e.g. have a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rawcontinue=true) json response it's from wikipedia. You can find details to the api [here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page#A_simple_example). A nice page is also [http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/).

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking at those now. So if I asked the website creators do implement that request, would it be a lot of work for them? And another website I found (website, not app) is already getting the data from the url I provided above. (See the link I'm about to post in another comment.)

Since this other website is already getting it, does that mean something must be implemented I don't know about and there is a way I can get it easily in JSON? (I need data from many different portions of the site; I have a meeting scheduled with the site creators but the less work for them the better.)

Comment: http://ushlstats.stats.pointstreak.com/prostatstext/USHL/teamstats_507791_12983.txt